# How to make a List of lines/Strings into sublists

Tags: scala, list, filter, sublist

Sorry if this has been asked before, but I have searched forever for a solution.

I have a list of strings;

```
val a = List("size 34", "help","panne","size 35","kake", "test","size 34", "help", "panne","size 35", "kake", "test")
```

I want to make them into a multiplelist.
Like;

```
val b = List("size 34", "help","panne")
val c = List("size 35","kake", "test")
```

I want to split the original list into a new list when it see the start a certain word, for example; It splits into a new list when the string starts with size.

I have figured out how just get the certain string with;

`val sequenceWithPlainAndGlazedDonut = a.filter { a => a.contains("size")}`

I want new lists from the word size(even if its more to the string, ie numbers) to the next time the word size is shown.

How is the best approch to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `foldLeft` or its symbolic version `/:`

```
val newList = (List.empty[List[String]] /: a) {(agg, elem) =>
  if (elem startsWith "size ") List(elem) :: agg
  else agg match {
    case head :: tail => (elem :: head) :: tail
    case Nil => agg
  }
}
```

This will give you the inner and outer lists in reverse order, you can do this if you need the original order:

```
newList.map(_.reverse).reverse
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks. Yours worked!

val e = a.foldLeft(Nil: List[String]) {(acc, next) => if (acc contains next) acc else next :: acc }.reverse
println(e)

This one is where i stopped. Almost. But how can i make the list of the list into then 3 seperate lists? Is there a neat function for that?

Comment: As long as you know it only has 3 elements: `val x :: y :: z :: Nil = newList`

Comment: 2 quick questions. You seem pretty godlike at this.
1. What was wrong with my code i commented to you?
2. What if it might have more values in one of the list. Ie elem 3 has 6 strings, while elem 2 only has 2?

Comment: Neat solution.  It might not matter to OP's use case, but I think `agg.head` will crash if the list doesn't start with an anchoring string (i.e. "size ...").

Comment: What to do depends on what the output should be if it doesn't start with a "size..." element.

Comment: The code you posted on the comment aggregates into a `List[String]`... which means a single flat list.

Comment: @Konrad UIV, depending on the specific business logic, one approach might be to expand the `else` case to something like `else if (agg == Nil) List(elem) :: agg else (elem :: agg.head) :: agg.tail`.

Comment: It should ignore it, or start the list and then make a new one when it hits the keyword. Ie, List(test,size,test,test,size,test) -> List(List(test),List(size,test,test,),List(size,test).

Comment: @LeoC Thanks that works. I tried to do a || in "if (elem startsWith "size " || "test")".
It returns || is not a member of the value. When I look at operator's, it says || is used?

Comment: Not sure what you mean on your second question. Are you referring to the `val x :: y :: z :: ...`? If you need a separate reference to each list, you **have** to know at compile-time how many elements the "outer" list will have. If you don't know that for sure, then you have to keep it as a nested list (exactly the type for when you don't know the number of elements at compile-time).

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I see. You said that in your answer "You can use foldLeft or its symbolic version" What would the foldleft code look like? Just trying to see how i went wrong in my attempt at it.

Comment: Same as the answer code, except for beginning like: `a.foldLeft(List.empty[List[String]]) {(agg, elem) => ...`

Answer (score 0):

If you have more values in the list, you can use Arrays to capture them.
See if the below works for you.

```
scala> val a = List("size 34", "help","panne","size 35","kake", "test","size 34", "help", "panne","size 35", "kake", "test")
a: List[String] = List(size 34, help, panne, size 35, kake, test, size 34, help, panne, size 35, kake, test)

scala> val b = a.sliding(3,3).toList
b: List[List[String]] = List(List(size 34, help, panne), List(size 35, kake, test), List(size 34, help, panne), List(size 35, kake, test))

scala> b(0)
res1: List[String] = List(size 34, help, panne)

scala> b.length
res6: Int = 4

scala>
```

Comment: Right. But if the 1st sub-list has 2 items and all the rest have 3 then none of the `sliding(3,3)` groups will be correct.

Comment: yes.. I meant that even if the entries are not evenly divided by 3, the     'a.sliding(3,3).toList doesn't throw error